# Outputting String to HTML using javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

there have been many questions like this before, but the answer usually involved referencing the element to be outputted to within the script. in my case, elements are created dynamically on load (it's hosted on Tumblr, to be specific), so there's no referable ID for each of the elements I need to output a string to.

is it possible to do this? jQuery can be used if it makes things much simpler. my function takes a string as an input and outputs a string using `return`.

Comment: *“my function takes a string as an input and outputs a string using `return`.”* What does the string it takes as input represent?

Comment: @minitech ah, right. it takes Tumblr's `{TagsAsClasses}` as an input, which is a string containing all the tags relevant specifically to that post.

Comment: `eval` all the things!

Comment: Can you please tell us what the elements you are looking to output too look like ? If you are going to output to them you should know them or know a parent of them.

Comment: the inside of an `<a>` tag, which is contained inside `<div class="posttext">`, which is inside one of many `<div class="post">` elements. all I need to do is output a single string to the inside of the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.post .posttext a')` -> this returns an array of `a` elements.

`$('.post').eq(the post number).find('.posttext a')` -> replace "the post number" with the number of your post if you want to target something more specific.

You can then call the `text("your text")` method to set the text.

Comment: I've gotten it working like that, this was the most helpful answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.post .posttext a').html(YourfunctionThatReturnsAString());
```

This should do it